# Como quitar decimales de un precio?

Tags: html, jquery

Quiero quitar los decimales de un precio '$ 336.760,00', que quede solo '$ 336.760'

```
<span class="precio">
   $ 336.760,00
</span>

var monto = $('.precio').text();
var montoFormat = monto.replace(/[$]/g,'');
console.log(montoFormat);
  
var myFloat = parseInt(montoFormat);
  
let sinDecimales = Math.trunc(myFloat);
console.log(sinDecimales);
```

intente de esta forma pero solo me deja 336

Comment: Eso es porque el parseInt encuentra un punto y se cree que está en dotación de punto en lugar de coma, y se come el resto pensando que son decimales. Prueba con `var montoFormat = monto.replace(/[$]/g,'').replace(/[.]/g,'').replace(/[,]/g,'.');`

Comment: me funciono, gracias bro.

Comment: @masterguru coloca eso en la respuesta y Daniel, luego procede a aceptar la respuesta, esto ayudará a mantener la buena salud del sitio, efecto del % de preguntas resueltas. Saludos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es porque el **parseInt()** encuentra un punto y por omisión se cree que está en dotación de punto en lugar de coma, y elimina el resto pensando que son decimales.

Prueba con

```
var montoFormat = monto.replace(/[$]/g,'').replace(/[.]/g,'').replace(/[,]/g,'.');
```

donde:

- `replace(/[$]/g,'')` elimina el signo de dollar
- `replace(/[.]/g,'')` elimina el punto de los miles en el formato actual
- `replace(/[,]/g,'.')` sustituye la coma por punto, separando correctamente los decimales tal como los espera el `parseInt()` que usarás después en esta linea:

```
var myFloat = parseInt(montoFormat);
```